# Slide over UITableViewCell, present another cell. Framework?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, gesture

I am trying to find either a framework or make one myself that can do this:

When you slide/swipe across a UITableViewCell, another cell gets displayed (with options such as Share on Twitter, Facebook, email etc).
The Twitter-app has got this, and I was wondering if there was an open framework for it.

If not, where do you recommend I start to make this on my own?

Thanks.

---

*To detect a swipe, use Apple's `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created the same thing a couple of months ago. Unfortunately, I can't find the code itself right now, but here are some guidelines:

1. To handle swipe gesture use examples like [this](http://devblog.wm-innovations.com/2010/03/30/custom-swipe-uitableviewcell/) or google - there are tons of swipe detection manuals :).
2. To show different view, use `[UIView beginAnimations]`. You may show new UIView instead of UITableViewCell's contentView.

Please let me know if you have questions.

Comment: It worked, thank you ! :)
Actually, I ended up using Apple's own swipe gesture recognizer, `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, one of many other `UIGestureRecogniser`'s.

Comment: Specifically how do you display the new view? By substituting it for the UITableView.contentView?